# R importing unequal number of columns per row correctly

Tags: r, rows

I have a dataset with over 40,000 rows and an unequal number of columns for each. The problem I am having is that each value at the end of each row belongs in the same column but its ending up divided among many different columns.

So my question is: Is there a simple way of asking that the final value of each row be placed in the same column?

headers are:
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11 c12 c13 c14

> BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU Acr3 GN=acr3 PE=4 SV=1 multidrug resistance
> BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA AdeI GN=adeI PE=4 SV=1 predicted protein
> BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA Multidrug efflux pump AbeM GN=abeM PE=4 SV=2 multidrug resistance protein

current import looks like this:

```
c1                                   c2        c3       c4     c5      c6        c7    c8  c9
BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU  Acr3      GN=acr3  PE=4   SV=1    multidrug resistance
BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA  AdeI      GN=adeI  PE=4   SV=1    predicted protein
BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA  Multidrug efflux   pump   AbeM    GN=abeM   PE=4 SV=2 multidrug efflux pump
```

If anything I'd like it to look like this:

```
c1                                   c2        c3       c4     c5    c6      c7   c8   c9
BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU  Acr3      GN=acr3  PE=4   SV=1  NA      NA   NA   multidrug resistance
BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA  AdeI      GN=adeI  PE=4   SV=1  NA      NA   NA   predicted protein
BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA  Multidrug efflux   pump   AbeM  GN=abeM PE=4 SV=2 multidrug efflux pump
```

but preferably like this:

```
c1                                                         c2   c3      c4   c5   c6
BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU                        Acr3 GN=acr3 PE=4 SV=1 multidrug resistance
BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA                        AdeI GN=adeI PE=4 SV=1 predicted protein
BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA Multidrug efflux pump  AbeM GN=abeM PE=4 SV=2 multidrug efflux pump
```

It is line 3 in this causing all the problems - I would prefer it if kept the name as one long string and didn't add those 3 extra columns, but as what I really want is the name(c1) and the description (last value) I am willing to deal with it this way if there in no other way.

But I was just thinking that perhaps there is a way of telling R how to divide the string - maybe so that all values after the "GN=*" value are placed into 3 individual columns. I don't know what would be best. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post a small sample of your data that illustrates your problem and what you would like to get?

Comment: Does it help if you specify `fill = TRUE` in `read.table()`?

Comment: `fill=TRUE` is used to left-fill rows with NAs. In this case I suggest you import all columns except c6-c8 (use option `colClasses`, explained in `?read.table`), read those columns on a second pass, and merge the data afterwards.

Comment: The problem is that the first line of each row sometimes has extra text and it is throwing of the entire import off. So importing all the columns before c6 won't do the trick.

Comment: You could try `scan("filename", what = character(), sep = " ")`, and then try to assemble the data frame.  Also, have you tried `fread` from the `data.table` package?

Comment: I played around with fread and it didn't work. Brought in the first line as a string no matter how I played around with sep values. There must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty messy file format. It would be better if you would separate fields with tabs or something that can be easily found in the line. As a human I had a hard time guessing where the breaks would be so i'm not surprised `read.table` has trouble to.

You could parse these strings with a regular expression. Something like

```
#lines <- readLines("filename.txt")
lines <- c("BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU Acr3 GN=acr3 PE=4 SV=1 multidrug resistance",
"BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA AdeI GN=adeI PE=4 SV=1 predicted protein","BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA Multidrug efflux pump AbeM GN=abeM PE=4 SV=2 multidrug resistance protein")

m <-regexpr("(.*) (\\w+) (GN=\\S+) (PE=\\S+) (SV=\\S+) (.*)", lines, perl=T)
```

This will report the start position and length of each of the columns. You can extract the values using substring or you can use a helper function like [regcapturedmatches](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321). If we take the results and propertly insert tabs between the fields, then we can use `read.table()` to make a data.frame

```
read.table(text=sapply( regcapturedmatches(lines,m), function(x) paste(x, collapse="\t")), sep="\t", as.is=T)
```

which gives

```
                                                         V1   V2      V3   V4   V5                           V6
1                       BAC0004|acr3|tr|B5LX01|B5LX01_CAMJU Acr3 GN=acr3 PE=4 SV=1         multidrug resistance
2                       BAC0017|adeI|tr|Q2FD95|Q2FD95_ACIBA AdeI GN=adeI PE=4 SV=1            predicted protein
3 BAC0001|abeM|tr|Q5FAM9|Q5FAM9_ACIBA Multidrug efflux pump AbeM GN=abeM PE=4 SV=2 multidrug resistance protein
```

which seems to match your desired result.

Comment: Awesome! That worked for the three lines, there are more columns in the line which I didn't include but using the same approach it is working. But what about the fact that the file is 40,000. I can use the readLines(file) but then for the lines<- c(....) what would I put there?

Comment: `readLines` should return a character array so you can use the results directly, just assign it to the variable `lines`.